# Fragment.onCreateView() not called in viewpager after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

After changing orientation, my activity with viewpager , which is list/detail kind,  is recreated and crashes if I select an item in a list.

I don't want to bother you with all the details (there is a nullpointerexception because a textview referenced in onCreateView() is null). 
My question is : How can ViewPager display 2 pages with a fragment in each one without even calling their onCreateView()?

How comes it works fine after application launch before turning the device?

I have only 2 pages/fragments.  But I saw with the debugger that 4 fragments are created when this activity is recreated. Do you know why and where this is documented?

Any solution? Thanks in advance for your help. I am at lost here because I don't control the fragments myself, viewpager does.

==========

Update  :  Please find below additional requested information

```
public class  DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView mDetailTV;
    // Retrieve the data to display from the parent activity
    private String getData() {
        ViewPagerActivity activity = (ViewPagerActivity)getActivity();
        return( activity.detailArray[activity.mPosition] );
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_detail_fragment, container, false);
        mDetailTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.detailTV);
        displayDetail(getData());   
        return view;
    }
    // Display data
    void displayDetail(String data) {       
        mDetailTV.setText(data);
    }
```

and the list and details fragments are instantiated and passed to Pager Adapter like that :

```
mListFragment = new ListFragmentt();
mDetailFragment = new DetailFragment();
mPagerAdapter = new MFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mListFragment, mDetailFragment);
```

Also, the data from the list/detail comes from the classical Skakespeare example, so I doubt there is out of memory on my Samsung S4.

Comment: can you post your activity oncreate code?

Comment: you could cache the views in case you don't have a lot of pages (or if you think they won't take a lot of memory), and just return the cached views for onCreateView. in addition, in order to avoid OOM, you could use WeakReference to the cached views in case you worry about memory

Comment: I tried a mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2) to cache pages but i still have the nullPointerException.  Do you mean we can cache for recreated activity?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by removing the onSaveInstanceState call of FragmentActivity superclass, like this:

protected void FragmentActivity(Bundle outState) {
}

but i still don't understand what's going on in the superclass of FragmentActivity. It was just an intuitive guess that succeeded. I don't understand the theory behind it. If anyone could try to explain a bit, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `ViewPager` caches your 2 neighbouring fragments. Therefore `onCreateView` need not to be called explicitly.